# Widgets options is miss in my new created theme

Tags: wordpress

I have created A new wordpress theme. but when I active this theme the widgets theme is missing .
My theme is just simple print "Hello World" in my theme body.
 I want to design my theme using widgets options. How can I add widgets options in my them.

please suggest me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to [register a widget area](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes) in your theme's functions.php

```
function twentyfifteen_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Widget Area', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyfifteen_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: I added same code in my theme function . but still widgets options is missing

Comment: it should be visible at Appearance -> widgets,
refresh your admin page and try again

Comment: any think I need to change in this code? because it's not working for me

Comment: where did you put it? can you send me your function.php?

Comment: <?php
function twentyfifteen_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Widget Area', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyfifteen_widgets_init' );
?>

Comment: and you can't find the widgets section in ADMIN AREA?

Comment: thanks @Narek Zakarian it is working now. I just work like a stupid the functions.php file was wrong there.I named it as function.php but it need to name as functions.php .